# Web Job not working when adding a new message on the Service Queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have configured continuously running web job to get triggered when the new message is added to the queue. But some time it is not getting triggered and if the web job is restrted it will start processing messages from queue and sometimes it is taking 10 to 15 minutes for the web job to get triggered.

Repro steps
When there is a new message in the storage queue, web job is not picking that message until we re-start the web-job.
Configure the web job to get triggered from queue
Add a message to the queue

Expected behavior
Expected behavior is that web job should get triggered immediately.

Actual behavior
Web job is not getting triggered until we restart the webjob and sometimes it taking 10 to 15 minutes to get triggered automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure functions directly. It will be triggered as soon as there is a new message been added.

This is the sample for C#.

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
    string messageId,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    log.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={enqueuedTimeUtc}");
    log.LogInformation($"DeliveryCount={deliveryCount}");
    log.LogInformation($"MessageId={messageId}");
}
```

If you want samples in other development languages. Here are the [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#example).

Reference:

[Compare Functions and WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#compare-functions-and-webjobs)

[Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#example)